# aws broken AuthFailure on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My aws is suddenly throwing error everywhere since yesterday.
(on windows terminal, WSL2 ubuntu) Couple days ago terraform worked fine. So I know aws credentials are accurate but to be sure I did

```
aws configure --profile mohit
Access Key ID [None]: aws_access_key_id
Secret Access Key [None]: default_secret_key
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: json
```

and executed

```
aws ec2 --profile mohit describe-instances --region ap-south-1
```

IAM user has Administrator access.So that rules out permission issues.
Also I tried Bunch of different regions, none worked.

```
An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

This error is consistent.

AWS says time might be out of sync with amazon.
I tried the solution and
`ntpdate[172]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting` this error popped.
Also

```
sudo service ntp stop
>> ntp: unrecognized service
```

and

`Fatal error : adjtimex(0x8001) failed : Function not implemented` on trying to do `chronyd`  on WSL2 ubuntu.

How do I fix this?

UPDATE :
I checked my BIOS and clock was off by 5 min there as well (I would love to know the reason) So I manually set it to time.gov UTC.
Problem Solved, but Reason is still unknown!

Comment: it's `service ntpd stop/restart`

Comment: The time thing is mentioned on AWS site : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-troubleshooting.html